# How to fix webdriverio error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

Hi I am new to webdriverio, I getting bellow error,
Cannot read property 'then' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null

Here is my code

```
it('Test case - User Add', () => {
browser.setTimeout({ implicit: 3111 })
userManagement.UserManagementMenu.click()
userManagement.NewUserButton.click()
userManagement.FirstName.setValue('EntryGate')
userManagement.Username.setValue('EGTestuser1')
userManagement.LastName.setValue('EGTestuser1')
userManagement.EmailAddress.setValue('EGTestuser1@test.com')
userManagement.Password.setValue('password1')
userManagement.Role.click().then(function(){
    browser.keys('ArrowUp')
    browser.keys('Enter')
})
userManagement.SaveUser.click()
});

});
```

following few google searches I figured out I am not handling the promise in my code.
can anybody correct my code[image: SampleCode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Official doc says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

> The then() method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

If you want to just perform click and some keyboard operation you can use below piece of code

```
 it('some description', () => {
      userManagement.Role.click();
      browser.keys('ArrowUp');
      browser.keys('Enter');
      userManagement.SaveUser.click();    
 }
```